# Accessing ENUM Values via a Loop Through a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, enums

I have an enum that would go as follows;

```
public enum Channels{
CHANNEL1,
CHANNEL2,
CHANNEL3,
CHANNEL4
}
```

I want to access these values through a JSP and display a label for each. For this purpose, I have created the following loop:

```
<c:forEach var="<%=Channels.values()%>" items="channel">
    <label>${channel}</label>
</c:forEach>
```

Whenever I run my JSP, it gives me an error and these values do not get displayed.

I also tried passing the values as model attributes as follows:

In the controller:

```
model.addAttribute("Channels", Channels.values());
```

In the JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="${Channels}" items="channel">
    <label>${channel}</label>
</c:forEach>
```

The ajax call to load the modal that contains this gives a 500 Internal Server Error whenever I try to do this.

Please let me know how I can fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this as follows;

In my controller, I set an attribute to pass the values of the ENUM as a string Array.

```
String Channels[] = Arrays.stream(ProductKdsChannels.values()).map(e -> e.toString()).toArray(String[]::new);
model.addAttribute("Channels" ,Channels);
```

In the JSP, access the attribute as usual, `${Channels}`

**Tip:** Make sure you put the box brackets [] near the variable name and not the data type. String[] Channels did not work for me.